# Rails - Couldn't find PackageRequest with 'id'=item_categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a package request model that handles all the tool loaning data. I am trying to have it so that when I go to the package request page in the application, that it shows only the form and not the index. So in the package request controller I tried to redirect the index path to the form path.

```
  def index
    @package_requests = PackageRequest.all
    redirect_to new_package_request_path
  end
```

But now when I try to go to a different page such as item categories from the package request form page I get this 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyBnn.png).

This kind of error shows up whenever I try to go to a different page from a form or show page.

log of server requests:

```
Started GET "/package_requests/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-03 18:43:55 -0500
Processing by PackageRequestsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  ItemLocation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "item_locations".* FROM "item_locations"
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items"
  Rendered package_requests/_form.html.erb (23.0ms)
  Rendered package_requests/new.html.erb within layouts/application (24.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 58.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/package_requests/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-03 18:44:01 -0500
Processing by PackageRequestsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"items"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  PackageRequest Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "package_requests".* FROM "package_requests" WHERE "package_requests"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find PackageRequest with 'id'=items):
  app/controllers/package_requests_controller.rb:68:in `set_package_request'


  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (46.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (40.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (89.4ms)
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  get "home", to: "static_pages#home"

  root 'home#home'
  resources :package_requests
  resources :zips
  resources :countries
  resources :states
  resources :cities
  resources :item_statuses
  resources :item_categories
  resources :buildings
  resources :tag_types
  resources :vendors
  resources :items
  resources :item_locations
  resources :loan_histories
  resources :order_requests
  resources :package_requests
  resources :home
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}
```

Comment: Could you please show us a log of the server requests?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still new to coding, where can I find that?

Comment: When you run `rails server` on a bash, the http requests are shown on that terminal.

Comment: Add your `routes.rb` file to the question.